# Looking for information on hosting/consuming Swift Package Manager artifacts in artifactory

Tags: swift, artifactory, swift-package-manager

Has anyone used artifactory to host packages created by the Swift Package Manager?

We would like to push these artifacts to Artifactory, and then consume them in various builds.

I'm going to install Artifactory locally and experiment. Hoping to short circuit that process.

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift Package Manager is not officially supported in JFrog Artifactory. You could absolutely use `generic repositories` to store your artifacts, though. Using either the REST APIs or the JFrog CLI, you could still store your artifacts and retrieve them from Artifactory. If you're an existing customer, I totally recommend reaching out to the support team to have them create a feature request.

Comment: There is now an open feature request for Artifactory to officially support SPM, however according to the comments it is in need of votes to get implemented: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-17276

Comment: Another update.  Artifactory does support SPM now.  
https://jfrog.com/blog/artifactory-your-swift-package-repository/